# Verify form inputs with Javascript before send it with POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to verify some inputs inside a form with javascript before send it with POST to a PHP controller.

the JS code looks like this, verifyng cellphone number, email, and password:

```
  function registerUser(){
        // Validate Email
        event.preventDefault();
        function validateEmail(email) {
          var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return re.test(email);
        }
        function validate() 
        {
          var email = document.getElementById("emailReg").val();
          if (validateEmail(email)) 
          {
            var celular = document.getElementById("cellReg").val();
            if(celular.lenght >= 10 && /[0-9]/.test(celular))
            {
              var pass = document.getElementById("passwordReg").val();
              if(pass.length >= 6 && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(pass))
              {
                alert("correct data");
                document.forms['registerForm'].submit(); 
              }
              else
              {
                // document.forms['registroForm'].submit(); 
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("password need to has at leas 6 characters and one uppercase");

              }
            }
            else
            {
              event.preventDefault();
              alert("Phone number must not have letters");
            }
          } 
          else 
          {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Incorrect e-mail");
          }
            return false;
        }
  }
```

this is the Form:

```
<form class="form row" method="POST" name="registerForm">

  <input type="email" class="form-reg" name="emailReg" id="emailReg" placeholder="example@email.com" style="width:140px;" required>

  <input type="text" class="formulario-registro" name="cellReg" id="cellReg" placeholder="cellphone number" style="width: 130px;" required>

  <input type="password" class="formulario-registro" name="passwordRegistro" id="passwordRegistro" placeholder="contraseña"  style="width: 140px;" required>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-qubit title" onclick="registroUser();">Registrarme</button>

</form>
```

I have to check the lenght and if the password has at least one uppercase, with the cellphone number if it has only numbers and at least 10 characters, if i write the **type="number"** property in the input tag it will appear with up and down arrows which i don't want to show, i could put the conditions in my php butin that way the form will get erased when i submit it and that's what i don't want to do.

Comment: *"i could put the conditions in my php butin that way the form will get erased when i submit it and that's what i don't want to do."*  Two points, the first being the most important.  **You need to have this validation in your php**.  Even if you have this validation in your javascript, the input validation and cleansing needs to at a minimum exist on your server.  You completely control what your server does.  You do not completely control what your users send your server.  Never trust that your frontend is validating everything.  Because a good programmer can get around your frontend.

Comment: Second point, in regards to the form getting erased.  This can either be remedied by either performing an ajax request for the validation before submitting the form, in which case it would update the page with errors if they are encountered.  Or, your form submit would need to repopulate the form with the inputs the user provided if there is an error, so they are not erased.

Comment: @Taplar actually the conditions are in my PHP controller, but as i wrote it, they get erased if some condition is invalid, about the Ajax it would be a solution but how could i resend the data based on the response? I know hot to send the data but almost never return it and print it in the form, i assume that will be with some  `var nomb = $(this).data('nomb');` ... i was thinking of it but i did not want to manipulate that information on the client side firstly just set some verifications

Comment: If you are performing an ajax request, the form would not be cleared out, because you are not performing a page transition.  You wouldn't need to reload the form fields with the data you sent.  They would still exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apply function **on submit** for the form... when it's submitted the JS code below verify if the conditions are true and then it is sended to the php controller.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".registerForm").on('submit', function(event)
    {
      var validate = validate();
      if(validate === "success")
      {
        console.log("success");
        document.forms['registerForm'].submit();
      }
      else{
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
    // validate password //
    function validate() 
    {
      var email = $("#emailRegister").val();
      if (validateEmail(email)) 
      {
        var cell = $("#cellRegister").val();
        if(cell.length === 10)
        {
          var pass = $("#passwordRegister").val();
          if(pass.length >= 6 && /[A-Z]/.test(pass))
          {
            console.log("correct data");
            return "success";
          }
          else
          {
            alert("password must have a lenght of 6 digits and at least one capital letter");
            return "false";
          }
        }
        else
        {
          alert("cellphone must be minimum a 10 digits number");
          return "false";
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
        alert("incorrect e/mail adress");
        return "false";
      }
    }

    // Validate Email
    function validateEmail(email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS for this issue

> > if i write the type="number" property in the input tag it will appear with up and down arrows which i don't want to show

```
/* Hide Up and Down arrows. */
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin: 0;
}
input[type="number"] {
-moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: it works in deed to hide the arrows. but not to verify the lenght, anyway it was very useful to my code. thanks